# MacOS : Latexmk together with Pythontex

Tags: latexmk, pythontex

I am a beginner in Latexmk. Pythontex works fine by typesetting with a shell, but I would like to test also with Latexmk.

I have installed it with TexLive, and I have a lot of rules preinstalled, including `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/pythontex-latexmkrc`.

When I try to typeset with `latexmk -xelatex /Users/jowe_19/Desktop/Finle_Name.tex`, the pythontex part does not work.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{pythontex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{pyconsole}
print(1)
\end{pyconsole}

\end{document}
```

RULE pythontex preinstalled with Mactex :

```
# Support for pythontex in v. 0.16 or higher, with latexmk 4.62 or higher
#
# What these definitions provide/do:
# 1. Variable specifying command string for invoking pythontex
# 2. Addition to %extra_rule_spec of template for pythontex rule. This
#    tells latexmkrc to create the rule when it is initializing for
#    processing a TeX file.
# 3. A subroutine mypythontex that the pythontex rule is defined to
#    call. This runs pythontex and then sets dependency information.
# 4. Settings for the files generated by the pythontex package and the
#    pythontex program so that the files are deleted in a clean-up
#    operation.

$clean_ext .= " pythontex-files-%R/* pythontex-files-%R";
push @generated_exts, 'pytxcode';

$pythontex = 'pythontex --interpreter python:/Users/jowe_19/opt/miniconda3/bin/python3 %O %S';
$extra_rule_spec{'pythontex'}  = [ 'internal', '', 'mypythontex', "%Y%R.pytxcode",  "%Ypythontex-files-%R/%R.pytxmcr",    "%R", 1 ];

sub mypythontex {
   my $result_dir = $aux_dir1."pythontex-files-$$Pbase";
   my $ret = Run_subst( $pythontex, 2 );
   rdb_add_generated( glob "$result_dir/*" );
   my $fh = new FileHandle $$Pdest, "r";
   if ($fh) {
      while (<$fh>) {
         if ( /^%PythonTeX dependency:\s+'([^']+)';/ ) {
         print "Found pythontex dependency '$1'\n";
             rdb_ensure_file( $rule, $aux_dir1.$1 );
     }
      }
      undef $fh;
   }
   else {
       warn "mypythontex: I could not read '$$Pdest'\n",
            "  to check dependencies\n";
   }
   return $ret;
}
```

LOG :

```
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 18 June 2019, version: 4.65.
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
Rule 'xelatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'xelatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf -recorder  "/Users/jowe_19/Desktop/Test_Latexmk.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/jowe_19/Desktop/Test_Latexmk.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3deprecation.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pythontex/pythontex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v3.4 <2019/11/09> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex)))) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newfloat/newfloat.sty
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def))
(./Test_Latexmk.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
No file pythontex-files-Test_Latexmk/Test_Latexmk.pytxmcr.
Run PythonTeX to create it.

Package PythonTeX Warning: Non-existent console content on input line 12.

[1] (./Test_Latexmk.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on Test_Latexmk.xdv (1 page, 988 bytes).
Transcript written on Test_Latexmk.log.
=== TeX engine is 'XeTeX'
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'pythontex-files-Test_Latexmk/Test_Latexmk.pytxmcr' from line
  'No file pythontex-files-Test_Latexmk/Test_Latexmk.pytxmcr.'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'Test_Latexmk.xdv'
Latexmk: applying rule 'xdvipdfmx'...
Rule 'xdvipdfmx': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'Test_Latexmk.xdv'
   Rule(s) that have been run and require run of dependent rule:
      'xelatex' which requires run of 'xdvipdfmx'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xdvipdfmx'
------------
For rule 'xdvipdfmx', running '&do_viewfile(  )' ...
------------
Running 'xdvipdfmx -o "Test_Latexmk.pdf"  "Test_Latexmk.xdv"'
------------
Test_Latexmk.xdv -> Test_Latexmk.pdf
[1]
4808 bytes written
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

Comment: Your example works for me.  What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Where do you have python installed. The default version that comes with macOS needs to have packages added to it. I've been using anaconda2 which has everything you could want for science pre-installed. That version of python is installed in `${HOME}/opt/anaconda2/bin` on my system so you need to change the line for `$pythontex` to `$pythontex = 'pythontex --interpreter python:${HOME}/opt/anaconda2/bin/python %O %S';` in the `latexmkrc` file (or `platexmkrc` if used with the TeXShop latexmk based engines).

Comment: @HerbSchulz : Python3 is here `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`. Besides, I changed the line `$pythontex = ...` into `$pythontex = 'pythontex --interpreter python:$/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 %O %S';` but it doesn't work.

Comment: There should be no $ just before the /Library. When you successfully run 'pythontex'  in Terminal what command line do you use? Is that run using python3 or the default python which is 2.x?

Comment: Also, `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3` so you probably should refer to it as such rather than through the physical location: the code should be `$pythontex = 'pythontex --interpreter python:/usr/bin/python3 %O %S';`

Comment: In a shell I use `pythontex FILE_NAME` and it is Python 3.

Comment: I tried with Miniconda 3, and with `$pythontex = 'pythontex --interpreter python:/Users/jowe_19/opt/miniconda3/bin/python3 %O %S';` it does't work.  I just added the log file in my initial post.

Comment: I see from the listing that latexmk doesn't even try to call pythontex.  That suggests that there is an error in your configuration. Did you actually copy the code from pythontex-latexmkrc to one of the standard latexmkrc files that latexmk reads?  If you didn't then pythontex won't be invoked, and the situation will be exactly the one you have.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I moved the rule latexmk pythontex in the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex` and called it `latexmkrc`, but Pythontex is not run again.

Comment: That's not one of the locations where latexmk looks for a latexmkrc file.  See the latexmk documentation in the section 'CONFIGURATION/INITIALIZATION (RC) FILES'.  Alternatively, use the `-r` option on the command line to latexmk to get it to read a specific initialization file in some other location.

Comment: Simple thing is to put the latexmkrc file into the same folder as your root .tex file.

Comment: Oh thanks ! : - ) Putting the file in `/usr/local/lib/latexmk`, it work's fine.

Comment: Good.  I'll make my comment an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened is that the user didn't put the initialization code in an initialization file that latexmk would read by default.  The solution is to put the code in a file that does read.  For information on the possible places, see the latexmk documentation in the section 'CONFIGURATION/INITIALIZATION (RC) FILES'.